# Neural net backprop code quality

Tags: c++, neural-network

This is my first neural net, previously I had it with just one hidden layer.
I have now given it an adjustable number of hidden layers. It all works perfectly (asin I dont get nans and infs). I have specifically avoided the use of pointers since I am still very new to coding and want to keep things as simple as possible, for now.
So I just want to know how likely it is that this code will cause me problems(I will add exception handling) or if anyone can spot any inefficiency's.
The formula I am for using backpropogation is as follows:

del == Gradient vector of, a(x) == preactivation function, h(x) == activation function, W == weights, B== bias, (-logf(x)y) == loss function valu,
e(y) == one hot vector (all 0's and one 1),
F(x) == output vector after activation (using softmax as i have 3 output neurons)

Compute output Gradient -> del a(L+1)(x)-logf(x)y <= -(e(y) - F(x))

for k from L+1 to 1

Compute hidden layer parameter gradients(weights gradients)

del W(k)-logf(x)y <= (del a(k)(x)-logf(x)y) h(k-1)(x)

del B(k)-logf(x)y <= del a(k)(x)-logf(x)y

Compute gradients of hidden layer below

del h(k-1)(x)- logf(x)y <= W(k) * (del a(k)(x)-logf(x)y)

del a(k-1)-logf(x)y <= (del h(k-1)(x)-logf(x)y) "dot" (activation derivitave(a(k-1)(x))

Using empirical risk minimization:

Delta = -del W-logf(x)y - (lamba*regularizer). //I have used L1

parameter = parameter + alpha*delta.

if this is not enough code and its okay to post more, please let me know, this is my first time posting here and Im wary of having too much to read.
this is the code:

```
    void backprop(Net& net, std::vector<double>& target)
    {//note to reader- The weights for each neuron is stored in the previous 
     //neuron as a vector
     // and the biases for each neuron is stored in the neuron itself as a 
     //double.
     // net.hiddenneurons is a two dimensional vector containing each layer 
     //of hidden neurons
        double PD{};
        for (size_t opd = 0; opd < net.outputneurons.size(); opd++)
        {
            net.outputneurons[opd].preactvalpd = -(target[opd] -net.outputneurons[opd].actval);
            PD = net.outputneurons[opd].preactvalpd * -1;
            net.outputneurons[opd].bias = net.outputneurons[opd].bias + (net.alpha * PD);
            PD = 0;
        }

        for (size_t hs = net.hiddenneurons.size()-1; hs > -1; hs--)
        {
            int layerup = hs + 1;
            for (size_t current = 0; current < net.hiddenneurons[hs].size(); current++)
            {
                if (hs == net.hiddenneurons.size() - 1)
                {
                for (size_t wpd = 0; wpd < net.hiddenneurons[hs] 
                [current].weights.size(); wpd++)
                {
                    PD = net.outputneurons[wpd].preactvalpd * 
                    net.hiddenneurons[hs][current].actval;
                    PD = PD * -1;
                    net.hiddenneurons[hs][current].weights[wpd] =
                    net.hiddenneurons[hs][current].weights[wpd] + (net.alpha 
                    * (PD - (net.lambda * 
                    regularizer(net.hiddenneurons[hs] 
                    [current].weights[wpd]))));//is this even correct 
                    //use of regularizer?
                    PD = 0;
                    //I have combined finding the partial derivative of the 
                    //weights with updating the 
                    //weights, PD is the partial derivative.
                    //I have done the same for biases.
                }
                for (size_t op = 0; op < net.outputneurons.size(); op++)
                {
                    PD += net.hiddenneurons[hs][current].weights[op] * 
                    net.outputneurons[op].preactvalpd;
                }

                net.hiddenneurons[hs][current].actvalPD = PD;
                PD = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                for (size_t wpd = 0; wpd < net.hiddenneurons[hs] 
                [current].weights.size(); wpd++)
                {
                    PD = net.hiddenneurons[layerup][wpd].preactvalpd * 
                    net.hiddenneurons[hs[current].actval;
                    PD = PD * -1;
                    net.hiddenneurons[hs][current].weights[wpd] =
                    net.hiddenneurons[hs][current].weights[wpd] + (net.alpha 
                    * (PD - (net.lambda * 
                    regularizer(net.hiddenneurons[hs] 
                    [current].weights[wpd]))));
                    PD = 0;
                }
                for (size_t op = 0; op < net.hiddenneurons[layerup].size(); 
                op++)
                {
                    PD += net.hiddenneurons[hs][current].weights[op] * 
                    net.hiddenneurons[layerup][op].preactvalpd;

                }
                net.hiddenneurons[hs][current].actvalPD = PD;
                PD = 0;
            }
            net.hiddenneurons[hs][current].preactvalpd = 
            net.hiddenneurons[hs][current].actvalPD * 
            tanhderiv(net.hiddenneurons[hs][current].preactval);
            net.hiddenneurons[hs][current].bias = 
            net.hiddenneurons[hs][current].bias + (net.alpha * 
            net.hiddenneurons[hs][current].preactvalpd);

         }
        }
        for (size_t iw = 0; iw < net.inneurons.size(); iw++)
        {
            for (size_t hpad = 0; hpad < net.inneurons[iw].weights.size(); 
            hpad++)
            {
                PD = net.hiddenneurons[0][hpad].preactvalpd * 
                net.inneurons[iw].val;
                PD = PD * -1;
                net.inneurons[iw].weights[hpad] = 
                net.inneurons[iw].weights[hpad] + (net.alpha * (PD - 
                (net.lambda * 
                regularizer(net.inneurons[iw].weights[hpad]))));
                PD = 0;
            }
    }
    std::cout << "backprop done" << '\n';
    }
```

Rest of code:

```
double randomt(int x, int y)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(x, y);
    return dist(mt);
}

class InputN
{
public:
    double val{};
    std::vector <double> weights{};
};
class HiddenN
{
public:
    double preactval{};
    double actval{};
    double actvalPD{};
    double preactvalpd{};
    std::vector <double> weights{};
    double bias{};
};
class OutputN
{
public:
    double preactval{};
    double actval{};
    double preactvalpd{};
    double bias{};
};
class Net
{
public:
    std::vector <InputN> inneurons{};
    std::vector <std::vector <HiddenN>> hiddenneurons{};
    std::vector <OutputN> outputneurons{};
    double lambda{ 0.015 };
    double alpha{ 0.015 };
};
void feedforward(Net& net)
{
    double sum{};
    int prevlayer{};
    for (size_t Hsize = 0; Hsize < net.hiddenneurons.size(); Hsize++)
    {
        //std::cout << "in first loop" << '\n';
        prevlayer = Hsize - 1;
        for (size_t Hel = 0; Hel < net.hiddenneurons[Hsize].size(); Hel++)
        {
            //std::cout << "in second loop" << '\n';
            if (Hsize == 0)
            {
                //std::cout << "in first if" << '\n';
                for (size_t Isize = 0; Isize < net.inneurons.size(); Isize++)
                {
                    //std::cout << "in fourth loop" << '\n';
                    sum += (net.inneurons[Isize].val * 
                    net.inneurons[Isize].weights[Hel]);
                }
                net.hiddenneurons[Hsize][Hel].preactval = 
                net.hiddenneurons[Hsize][Hel].bias + sum;
                net.hiddenneurons[Hsize][Hel].actval = tanh(sum);
                sum = 0;
                //std::cout << "first if done" << '\n';
            }
            else
            {
                //std::cout << "in else" << '\n';
                for (size_t prs = 0; prs < 
                     net.hiddenneurons[prevlayer].size(); prs++)
                {
                    //std::cout << "in fourth loop" << '\n';
                    sum += net.hiddenneurons[prevlayer][prs].actval * 
                    net.hiddenneurons[prevlayer][prs].weights[Hel];
                }
                //std::cout << "fourth loop done" << '\n';
                net.hiddenneurons[Hsize][Hel].preactval = 
                net.hiddenneurons[Hsize][Hel].bias + sum;
                net.hiddenneurons[Hsize][Hel].actval = tanh(sum);
                //std::cout << "else done" << '\n';
                sum = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //std::cout << "first loop done " << '\n';
    int lasthid = net.hiddenneurons.size() - 1;
    for (size_t Osize = 0; Osize < net.outputneurons.size(); Osize++)
    {
    
        for (size_t Hsize = 0; Hsize < net.hiddenneurons[lasthid].size(); 
        Hsize++)
        {
            sum += (net.hiddenneurons[lasthid][Hsize].actval * 
            net.hiddenneurons[lasthid][Hsize].weights[Osize]);
        }
        net.outputneurons[Osize].preactval = net.outputneurons[Osize].bias + 
        sum;
    } 
}
void softmax(Net& net)
{
    double sum{};
    for (size_t Osize = 0; Osize < net.outputneurons.size(); Osize++)
    {
        sum += exp(net.outputneurons[Osize].preactval);
    }
    for (size_t Osize = 0; Osize < net.outputneurons.size(); Osize++)
    {
        net.outputneurons[Osize].actval = 
        exp(net.outputneurons[Osize].preactval) / sum;
    }
}
double regularizer(double weight)
{
    double absval{};
    if (weight < 0) absval = weight - weight - weight;
    else if (weight > 0 || weight == 0) absval = weight;
    else;
    if (absval > 0) return 1;
    else if (absval < 0) return -1;
    else if (absval == 0) return 0;
    else return 2;
    // I will add a exception handler for when this function returns 2
} 

void lossfunc(Net& net, std::vector <double> target)
{
    int pos{ -1 };
    double val{};
    for (size_t t = 0; t < target.size(); t++)
    {
        pos += 1;
        if (target[t] > 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    for (size_t s = 0; net.outputneurons.size(); s++)
    {
        val = -log(net.outputneurons[pos].actval);
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::vector <double> invals{ };
    std::vector <double> target{ };
    Net net;
    InputN Ineuron;
    HiddenN Hneuron;
    OutputN Oneuron;
    int IN = 4;
    int HIDLAYERS = 1;
    int HID = 8;
    int OUT = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < IN; i++)
    {
        net.inneurons.push_back(Ineuron);
        for (int m = 0; m < HID; m++)
        {
            net.inneurons.back().weights.push_back(randomt(0, 1));
        }
    }
    //std::cout << "first loop done" << '\n';
    for (int s = 0; s < HIDLAYERS; s++)
    {
        net.hiddenneurons.push_back(std::vector <HiddenN>());
        if (s == HIDLAYERS - 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < HID; i++)
            {
                net.hiddenneurons[s].push_back(Hneuron);
                for (int m = 0; m < OUT; m++)
                {
                    net.hiddenneurons[s].back().weights.push_back(randomt(0, 
                    1));
                }
                net.hiddenneurons[s].back().bias = randomt(0, 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < HID; i++)
            {
                net.hiddenneurons[s].push_back(Hneuron);
                for (int m = 0; m < HID; m++)
                {
                    net.hiddenneurons[s].back().weights.push_back(randomt(0, 
                    1));
                }
                net.hiddenneurons[s].back().bias = randomt(0, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    //std::cout << "second loop done" << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < OUT; i++)
    {
        net.outputneurons.push_back(Oneuron);
        net.outputneurons.back().bias = randomt(0, 1);
    }
    //std::cout << "third loop done" << '\n';
    int count{};
    std::ifstream fileread("N.txt");
    for (int epoch = 0; epoch < 500; epoch++)
    {
        count = 0;
        fileread.clear(); fileread.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        while (fileread.is_open())
        {

            std::cout << '\n' << "epoch: " << epoch << '\n';
            std::string fileline{};
            fileread >> fileline;
            if (fileline == "in:")
            {
                std::string input{};
                double nums{};
                std::getline(fileread, input);
                std::stringstream ss(input);
                while (ss >> nums)
                {
                    invals.push_back(nums);
                }
            }
            if (fileline == "out:")
            {
                std::string output{};
                double num{};
                std::getline(fileread, output);
                std::stringstream ss(output);
                while (ss >> num)
                {
                     target.push_back(num);
                }
            }
            count += 1;
            if (count == 2)
            {
                for (size_t inv = 0; inv < invals.size(); inv++)
                {
                    net.inneurons[inv].val = invals[inv];
                }
                //std::cout << "calling feedforward" << '\n';
                feedforward(net);
                //std::cout << "ff done" << '\n';
                softmax(net);
                printvals("output", net);//this is just to print weights and 
                //biases
                std::cout << "target: " << '\n';
                for (auto element : target) std::cout << element << " / ";
                std::cout << '\n';
                backprop(net, target);
                invals.clear();
                target.clear();
                count = 0;
            }
            if (fileread.eof()) break;
        }
    }
    //std::cout << "fourth loop done" << '\n';

    return 1;
 }
```

I know there is probably quite a lot of inefficiency's in the code, while i dont expect anyone to point all if it out. It would be much apreciated to just point out the biggest problems, I am still learning and any criticism is more than welcome.
The input file looks as follows: Example-
in: 0.45 0.62 0.78 0.94
out: 0.0 0.0 1.0
This comes from a function i wrote that basically just adds a 4 random numbers into a vector, sums those 4 numbers and if sum is below 1 output is 1.0 0.0 0.0, if sum is between 1 and 2 output is 0.0 1.0 0.0 and otherwise 0.0 0.0 1.0.

Just a note to anyone wondering, this is a personal project. I am not in university or school, I am self learning :). so this is not homework or something.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. Questions can contain up to 64K characters and this question is no where close to that. The longer the code is the better we can review it. You might want to make sure that the code is indented in the question the way it is on your computer.

Comment: The info is much apreciated! I copied all the code exactly from my compiler and just added 4 spaces to every line. It all looks the same when i cross reference. :)

Comment: Just FYI, once you have an answer you should not update the question. You can start a follow up question with any new code.

Comment: awesome, I will keep that in mind :) thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the possibility, that you're going to provide us the full code soon, some hints at first glance:

1. Your routine backprop() is too large. I'm not an absolute supporter of always small smart methods/function-bodies, but in your case, sub methods should be considered for better readability.
2. Your variable PD has a too 'global' context/scope within your routine, but that's not necessary. Whenever possible, locals should be declared near their actual usage scope. Don't care about performance here if that was your intention! All modern compilers will do their job here perfectly.
3. Try to use a quite consistent naming always (as does apply on case sensitivity consistency)! For simple running variables, that's often not a problematic issue but as soon as more context is actually required, a helpful clean naming can save you hours in understanding your own code several months later... :) Especially as a personal preference, I like the distinction between members and locals/parameters.
4. With a view on performance: Vectors of vectors can slow down your algorithm in doubt if not used with care (see cache behavior). If that's going to play a more important role here for you, try to profile that early within the development state of your application to be sure, you're using robust 'fundamental' data structures.

Comment: I see, okay I will work on adjusting the backprop code! once I am done, I will add it to the code in question, I will then comment that I have adjusted and if you are available to check it out, hopefully it will be much better :) Much appreciated!

Comment: Updated :), the net still works in that it doesnt spit out NANS, but it still is not really learning.(the softmax output vals dont move away from around 0.55 0.46 0.02 ).